# uniformly random access a collection

Tags: java, random, uniform

I wanna implement a uniformly random access to a certain collection with N numbers, like each item in the collection will be accessed at uniformly 1/N chances. I put all the items in a modified double linked-list. then circular shift it with random times, remove the last item then add it as first. finally pick the first item. I used it to test how many number of calls it will take to cover all the item without moving the item out of the list. Mine total number needed is consistently units less than expected. Wondering if the implementation is truly uniformly random? do you think my implementation is truly random?I have been debugging this for quite some time, still no clue.

```
public Item callout(){
       for (int j=0; j<StdRandom.uniform(N); j++)
        {
            this.addFirst(this.removeLast()); 
// circular shift the queue by StdRandom.uniform(N)times, always return the first item;
        }
       return first.item;
   } 

public void addFirst(Item item){
   Node<Item> oldfirst = first;
   first = new Node<Item>();
   first.item = item;
   first.previous = null;

if (last == null) 
       {last = first;  first.next = null;} //if it's the first element added.   if last.next = null == last = null;!!!! 
   else 
   {
       first.next = oldfirst;
       oldfirst.previous = first;
   }
    N++;
 }

public Item removeLast(){
 if (last == null) throw new RuntimeException();
 Item item = last.item;


 // if right now only one element exists in the container
  if (first == last)
 {
   first=null;
   last=null;
 }

 else{
 last =last.previous;
 last.next = null;   
 // old first becomes first;    optional operation, easy way to tell if it's the header.
 }
   N--;

 return item;
 }
```

The following class computes the number of calls needed to reach comprehensive call, it receives a RandomCollection with n items in it. Basically, It's a collection with Integers from 1-N, I use an array int[] of flag to tag if the item has previously been called.

```
private static int getNumberOfCallsForComprehensiveCallout(RandomCollection<Integer> test, int n){
    // create an array of the same number of items in collection, each with a Flag indicating whether it has beeen called
    int calltimes =0;     // calltimes stands for the numofcalls needed to reach a comprehensive call
    int flag = 1;     // flag used to indicate if this item has been called
    int [] c = new int [n];
      Arrays.fill(c, flag);
      int NumberOfFlags = n;


    while(NumberOfFlags != 0){
        int numbercalled = test.callout();
        if (c[numbercalled-1]==1) {NumberOfFlags--; c[numbercalled-1]=0;}
        else;   // indicate this item has been called earlier.
        calltimes++;
    //  System.out.println(calltimes);

    }
    return calltimes;   // return the number of calls for comprehensive callout each time this method is called.
}
```

Comment: Code layout is borked. What seems to be the problem anyway?

Comment: layout modified. I wanna implement a uniformly random access to a certain collection, I put all the items in a modified double linked-list.  then circular shift it, always pick the first item to test how many number of calls it will take to cover all the item without moving the item out of the list. Mine total number needed is less than estimate. Wondering if the implementation is truly uniformly random?  do you think my implementation is truly random?

Comment: 'randomness' is a tricky thing. Taking the Nishanth's fix into account, it depends on the numbers generated by `StdRandom.uniform(N)`. Note that 'truly random' is _really_ hard to achieve; when people talk about 'random number generators' (RNGs) they are often referring to _pseudo_ random number generators (PRNGs). A good PRNG appears random but its sequence is completely determined by an initial seed value. It depends entirely on intended use whether 'random' is random enough.. You may be interested in the 'die hard' randomness tests if you want to know how random your code is.

Answer (score 1):

The overall logic seems to be correct, but -

Firstly, the number of calls to cover all the items (with replacement) can be greater than size of the collection. Infact it will be greater most of the times.

Secondly, in `callout()`, call the `StdRandom.uniform(N)` method outside the loop *only once*. try the following change -

```
public Item callout(){
    int randomRotate = StdRandom.uniform(N);
    for (int j = 0; j < randomRotate; j++)
    {
        this.addFirst(this.removeLast()); 
    }

    return first.item;
}
```

I ran some simulations and the number of rotations are not uniformly distributed if the call to `StdRandom.uniform(N)` is made inside the `for` loop. Histogram results for a collection of size 10 -

```
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
1001 1813 2074 2043 1528  902  454  144   37    4
```

Comment: I totally get your point. the second block of source code is what I used to compute the number of calls needed to reach comprehensive calls. Any problem you think? In my opinion, the method is pretty clear. My concern is callout did not visit items uniformly random, you think it is uniformly random?

Comment: The number of rotations is definitely not uniform. Check my second point.

Comment: wow! you make my day. and your way to test if it's random is inspiring to me, too! many thanks.

Comment: Plotting the histogram is interesting: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B1001%3B+1813%3B+2074%3B+2043%3B+1528%3B++902%3B+454%3B+144%3B+37%3B+4%5D). Certainly looks familiar; instead of uniform you made a Gaussian(?) distribution :-)

Comment: Interesting! looks like a combination of log-normal and exponential distribution.